# Cant get token from B2C / Azure AD (Active Directory) - Local Storage & Session Storage are empty [Cypress / Puppeteer]

Tags: azure, token, storage, puppeteer, cypress

So, I run tests on Cypress, but my company now decided to switch to B2C Azure AD , so now my login automated test on cypress doesnt work anymore. Therefore, I went to my google friend to search for solutions, and most people seems to recommend using puppeteer to grab the login token and return it to cypress, so that it can resume the next tests.

The problem, however, is that on Local Storage or Session Storage (tab "Application" of the devtools), at no moment there is any "key" or "value", so there is never any token there - Not before the login, not during the login, not after the login. They are always empty. From all examples I saw, people always grab the token from Local Storage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the session storage? There should be an AccessToken available there once you are logged in.